# Insert pair containig non copyable object into map

Tags: c++, stdmap, std-pair

Given this map:

```
map<string,pair<mutex,set<string>>> m;
```

I would like to insert new elements at a key if they don't exist already. I could do this using the `operator[]`, i.e.:

```
string possibly_new_key{"foo"};
m[possibly_new_key];
```

this will default construct my `pair<mutex,set>`, which is also what I want. The problem is that the performance of my program is my first and last concern. For that reason I would like to use `map::insert` or `map::emplace_hint` and use a hint (which I have to compute beforehand anyways) to "insert if it doesn't exist". But I cannot figure out how to call that function correctly because no matter what I try, either

1. std::pair default construction is ill-formed, or
2. std::mutex is not copyable and compilation fails.

What I kind of want (and doesn't work):

```
auto it=m.lower_bound(possibly_new_key);
//do_stuff_with_it(it);
auto new_value=make_pair(mutex{},set<string>{});
m.emplace_hint(it, piecewise_construct, forward_as_tuple(possibly_new_key), forward_as_tuple(new_value));
```

Is there a way to accomplish this using a hint, and either just default constructing the new value or providing a default constructed one and moving it?

Answer (score 1):

Found out how it works!

`emplace` can actually take empty parameters to default construct piecewise. With `std::forward_as_tuple()` such a parameter is passed. So what I ended up with was:

```
m.emplace_hint(it, piecewise_construct, forward_as_tuple(possibly_new_key), forward_as_tuple());
```

This solution does everything I wanted in the first place, it uses a hint to possibly have amortized constant complexity and it default constructs the mapped type in place.

Answer (score 0):

All the elements of the standard containers must be copyable.
You can use shared pointers as copyable elements:

```
struct MutexSetStr
{
  std::mutex            mutex;
  std::set<std::string> data;
};
std::map< std::string, std::shared_ptr<MutexSetStr> > m;

std::shared_ptr<MutexSetStr> new_value(new MutexSetStr);
new_value.mutex.reset(new std::mutex);
m[new_key] = new_value; // or any other method to insert
```

Comment: copyable _or movable_. Also, prefer `std::make_shared()` over `std::shared_ptr{new ...}`; most users should never have to write `new` or `delete`.

Comment: @underscore_d Possible. In fact, my expertise is c++03. Don't hesitate to produce an answer more "fresh". :-p

Comment: My understanding is that in modern c++ there is no specific requirement on the type used in a map (depending on which methods are used), therefore I tried using `emplace()` as it's only requirement should be some kind of constructability.